# Trigger new onException route from onRedelivery

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

I have an `ErrorHandler` (`DefaultErrorHandler`) into which I have provided an `onRedelivery` ref. By default the `ErrorHandler` retries unlimited times. However, if a certain condition exists (currently determined by the `onRedelivery` ref) I would like to exit the redelivery loop and execute a different route.

My initial thought was to have the `onRedelivery` ref throw and exception and have an appropriate `onException` direct this to the appropriate route. However, I find that the `RedeliveryErrorHandler` catches this exception and keeps looping.

I have also found that I can set the `Exchange.REDELIVERY_EXHAUSTED` to true which will exit the redelivery loop but will not direct me to my recovery route.

Any suggestions?

`Edit`

So I have found that if I add the original exception type to the `onException` of the exception type in the `RouteBuilder` in which I have my `ErrorHandler`, and if I set the `Exchange.REDELIVERY_EXHAUSTED` to true, the original exception will be thrown to the `RouteBuilder` scope and caught by the `onException`. However, I would really prefer to throw and catch a new exception type so that the handling is explicit to this case.

`Answer`

So `Peter's` suggestion of using `retryWhile` was great in that it allows me to programmatically determine when to stop retrying. It's too. It only went half way thought. The second part was to send the failing exchange to a new / different route for error handling. This is accomplished by using the `DeadLetterChannel` instead of the `DefaultErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `retryWhile` in combination with `deadLetterChannel`:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:special")
            .retryWhile(method(new MyPredicate())));

        from("direct:start")
            .log("Starting...")
            .throwException(new Exception("dummy"));

        from("direct:special")
            .log("...Special");
    }
}

public class MyPredicate implements Predicate {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(final Exchange exchange) {
        AtomicInteger counter = exchange.getProperty("myCounter");
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
            exchange.setProperty("myCounter", counter);
        }
        int count = counter.incrementAndGet();
        LOG.info("Count = {}", count);
        return count < 3; // or whatever condition is suitable
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
INFO  Starting...
INFO  Count = 1
INFO  Count = 2
INFO  Count = 3
INFO  ...Special
```

Comment: Hi Peter, you should not store the state information (count) into the MyPredicate instance. Keeping the Predicate instance stateless could avoid some wired error when there are more than one exception need to handled.

Comment: @WillemJiang Thanks for the hint. I updated my example accordingly.

Comment: +1 This looks exactly right. I am going to test to see if it works before marking as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter, it's Better now :)